# Redirect issues with htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like redirect http://example.com/index.php?a=music to http://example.com/music (where the number is a variable/dynamic). My site is http : / / example . com

I added the following line to my mod-rewrite rules in my .htaccess file:

```
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$/?/a/=(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php?a=$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. I know I'm doing something wrong, I'm just not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Best,
Jeff

Edited:
Thanks Tom,

This is what I have:

```
    Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: By "number", do you mean the word "music" in your example?

Comment: Yes, I tried to implement, but I'm clearly doing something wrong.My edited is where I started.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?a=$1 [L]
```